# Be notified if the Question you are answering is deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, answers

I was answering a question.

I submitted a quick answer first. Just two lines of code that provided a satisfactory solution.

Then I edited my answer by including a working jsFiddle (*[for your mild amusement](http://jsfiddle.net/hcF34/)*) and a step by step explanation of my code.

When I submitted my edit, after a few minutes of typing, I got a `Page Not Found` error. There was no notification or mention of the fact that the question was deleted, which is what must have happened. This felt pretty frustrating and annoying.

It'd be nice to at minimum get a notification that a question is deleted when you try and submit your edit, and it'd be even better if the notification popped up when the deletion happened, so as to save you some time.

Also, now I don't know if my edits have been saved, in case the OP decides to undelete the question.

( *For reference [this was the post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866462/)* )

Comment: @Lance - Yikes! - I can't believe I wrote `"your"` for `"you are"`. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Your edit was saved; I saw it.

Comment: @SLaks - Thanks for the info. Another 3.7K 'till I can see it too ;)

Comment: It would also be nice to notify the OP of an ongoing edit when he tries to delete, but I guess that's not so easy to implement (how should the server know that the editor changed his mind and closed the edit window again?)

Answer (score 5):

If this is so, it's a regression; the 45 second heartbeat routine checked for this in the past and would tell you if the question was closed, deleted, etc.

Yep. No repro. Works and confirmed on dev.

[image]

Ah, I can repro it **when editing** -- I tested when adding a new answer. Will fix!

Comment: Thanks for trying to repro. It looks like this is for an initial answer? Do you get the same notification if you're editing an already existing answer when the question is deleted?

Comment: @peter I see, the URL you provided is incorrect. Disregard my previous comments -- but, it's still no-repro at least for new answers. Looking at editing

Comment: Wait, why is this important if the answer is being *edited*? Aren't edits to deleted answers still accepted?

Comment: @Shoq9 - I started editing the answer when it was not deleted yet. Then when I hit `"Save Edits"`, I got a `Page Not Found`, and I couldn't see whether my edits were saved or what had happened to the question (I am < 10K) ----- This is also why I apparently provided an incorrect URL... I can't see the question or my answer.