# Implement a JavaScript alert when a question you're answering is deleted

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I've just spent ~25 minutes coding [this](http://jsfiddle.net/36dWe/2/) from existing knowledge, and using it alongside an answer I'd written to a question. During the time I'd spent putting my answer together, [this question was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639579/mark-a-row-across-different-divs-with-jquery/15639698#15639698).

Was I warned when the question was deleted? No, I wasn't. My only warning came when I tried to post the answer (well, actually, undelete the answer as I'd accidentally posted it too soon previously):

[image: Example image]

I can't imagine this happens all too often, but my request is this: could some sort of JavaScript `alert()` dialogue be put in place to immediately alert us when questions we're viewing are deleted?

This is similar to [Display notification when the question you are answering is voted as dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15663/display-notification-when-the-question-you-are-answering-is-voted-as-dupe?rq=1)

Comment: +1 Has happened to me before too.

Comment: Related: [Notification of question closure whilst answering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93081)

Comment: It already *should* notify you the post is deleted: [Be notified if the Question you are answering is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66694). If it didn't then either it was *just* deleted (too soon for the notification to show) or something is b0rken.

Comment: The post looks interesting enough to keep, so I undeleted it.  In other news, someone trying to use divs instead of tables in an attempt to be semantically correct, and it's actually tabular data.  Sigh.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's great, but it's not very helpful when you're already scrolled half-way down a page or putting something together in a different browser tab or window. Most browsers treat JavaScript `alerts` as important and will either take you straight to that tab (if the browser window is in focus) or make the browser icon in the task bar flash (on Windows 7, at least).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Op got his first revision in before the question was deleted.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I am aware of that; are you saying that cancels the notification then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey ah thanks for that! It's good to know that answers in this situation do remain saved. I'd still like to see something like this put in place though (for the reasons stated in my previous comment).

Comment: @Martijn: Well, it's not posting an answer at that point, is it?  It's an edit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The OP wanted to see a notification on the page while still open in his browser before even attempting to undelete and edit the answer, I think. Does the notification only show up when you enter a new `Your Answer` text box?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Hm, well according to the timeline the answer was last edited 24 minutes ago, 14 minutes after the OP deleted their post 38 minutes ago. You can still edit the answer, you just can't undelete it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That is what we are talking about. Was there supposed to be a banner notification on the page for the previous 14 minutes so the OP learned *earlier* that his efforts were being wasted?

Comment: So we're talking about getting notification of an OP deletion against an answer edit that is allowed anyway.  That's a little different than getting your work tossed, which is what happens when you try and post a new answer on a question that has just been deleted.

Comment: Ideally I think a notification should appear at any situation as soon as an answer is deleted - regardless of what you're doing (viewing, commenting, editing, answering). Having this as just an element being fixed to the very top of the page (which seems to already be in place) isn't greatly noticeable when you're not scrolled to the top of the page or do not have that particular page in focus.