# Show "This question has been deleted" in the app while writing new answer

Tags: feature-request, android-app, deleted-questions

Would it be possible in the android app for the user responding to a question to be notified if the OP decides to delete the question?

I just spent 15 minutes typing an answer on Math.SE (involving lots of MathJax markup) only to be told on completing it that the question had been deleted.

This is already the case on the site, so requesting to add this to the app as well.

Comment: This really hurts!! I hate to see this happen but that's how the system is designed to work... or may be something is there and I missed it... either way I would be glad to be corrected

Comment: You should see a banner when it happens: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66694/be-notified-if-the-question-you-are-answering-is-deleted if you don't see such banner then it's a bug

Comment: @ShadowWizard you're correct in a one way... what I mean to say that the banner is shown to the answerer who is drafting the answer BUT it's not true for the OP... Does OP(the original questioner) sees a similar kinda banner while deleting post?

Comment: @ShadowWizard pretty sure i didn't see a banner, or any indication until I'd finished my answer and pressed Post. I'll add the "bug" tag. I'm using the Android app.

Comment: Ahhh - you were posting the answer with the android app?? If so, I'd recommend making that a bit more clearer, at the top of your question - as the banner already exists *on the site*, but if you want it for android, it'd be a feature-request

Comment: @ShadowWizard cc^^

Comment: @IanF1 I've radically changed this to be a focused feature request for the android app. If you want to request same thing for iOS app and/or mobile theme of the sites, please do this with separate questions. Also, removed lots of background information that isn't really required in a general feature request. Hope you understand!

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's fine - thanks!